# Showing full list of names of features within polygon when hovering over it in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon, visualisation

In QGIS I've successfully joined three tables of data: *'Addresses'*, *'Persons'*, and *'Polygons'*. The polygons represent the address on the map, and each address "contains" the names of all people on that address:

[image]

I want to use Display/Map tips to show a list of all people on every address when hovering over the polygon corresponding to the address. I've done this by pasting `[% "Person_Name” %]` in the Display tab of the properties.

However, I cannot figure out how to print a full list of names. Only the first name on the list appears:

[image]

Is there a solution to print a full list of names when hovering over the address/polygon?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Can using ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` to join the tables be an option?

For each address, a list of the names is created. The map tip is then displayed when hovering over the virtual layer.

```sql
select  p.adress, 
        p.geometry, 
        group_concat(a.name) as residents from Polygons p
left join adress a
on p.adress = a.adress
group by p.adress
```

[image]

.

[image]
.
[image]

Comment: BERA, Thank you so, so much! It worked perfectly, and I think that I understand what I did, haha. What I can't figure out (since I know no SQL yet) though, is how to add other information about the people. Let's say that I want to add Erik's gender or age or something. I've tried for a few hours now, but I'm really not getting anywhere. Thanks again!

Comment: Nice! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers   You mean in the map tip you want to show name (from one column) and age (from another)?